# php foreach loop failing to iterate when temporary variables are used

Tags: php, for-loop, php-5.6

I am trying to iterate through a simple php array, and have run into bizarre behavior that is causing iteration to terminate early. My php version is 5.6.3.

The following code prints the numbers 1 through 5, as expected...

```
$values = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    foreach ($values as $v)
        //$temp_variable = $v;
        echo "v: " . "$v" . "\n";
```

[image]

However, if I uncomment the line with the temporary variable, like so, we only get one iteration!

```
$values = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    foreach ($values as $v)
        $temp_variable = $v;
        echo "v: " . "$v" . "\n";
```

[image]

This seems extremely bizarre. How could the act of creating an unused temporary variable cause our loop to go off-the-rails? Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not bizarre, if you don't encompass the code in curly braces `{}` then foreach only executes the line immediately after it:

```
foreach ($values as $v)
    $temp_variable = $v; //foreach ONLY runs this line in the loop
    echo "v: " . "$v" . "\n";
```

Change it to:

```
foreach ($values as $v) {
    $temp_variable = $v;
    echo "v: " . "$v" . "\n";
}
```

Now everything inside the braces is part of the loop. This is the same with basically every other control structure in PHP:

```
if($condition === TRUE)
    echo 'True.'; //this line will run if the statement is true.
else
    echo 'False'; //only this line will run if the statement is false.
echo 'Something else'; //this line will run no matter what, but only once.
```

Comment: You noticed that pretty fast. Well done. +1

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I think I've been spending too much time with python...